# Passando variáveis pela URL utilizando URL amigáveis via GET

Tags: php, url, url-amigável, url-rewrite

Estou tentando mexer com URL amigáveis. Antes, para passar as variáveis eu usava por exemplo:

```
pagina.php?variavel=valordavariavel
```

clicando nesse link eu poderia usar um `echo` e exibir a variável. Agora estou tentando utilizar a URL amigável então tecnicamente nao existe mais o **`pagina.php?variavel=valordavariavel`**.

Fica só:

```
pagina/valordavarivel
```

Porém, não consigo transformar esse valor em uma variável PHP para poder exibi-la. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Faz MUITO tempo que não faço reescrita de URL (roteamento é muito melhor) mas, assumindo que esteja funcionando, `$_GET['variavel']` não ecoa **valordavariavel**?

Comment: [Implementando URL amigáveis com roteamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escrevi o código abaixo para mostrar algo mais "sofisticado", conforme propõe o desafio.

O primeiro ponto que me chamou atenção foi o seguinte trecho na pergunta do AP

> clicando nesse link eu poderia usar um echo e exibir a variável. Agora
>   estou tentando utilizar a URL amigável então tecnicamente nao existe
>   mais o pagina.php?variavel=valordavariavel.

Pode não ser o caso do AP, mas devemos estar ciente de que mesmo uma URL no formato de URL amigável (URL Rewrite), deve permitir acesso por pelo modo normal.

Muitos sistemas, equivocadamente constroem suas URLs ignorando o modo normal de montar parâmetros de URL. Isso é um problema pois não permite que o sistema seja utilizado em ambientes que não possuam recurso de URL amigável.

Desse script abaixo, destacos pontos diferentes da maioria das "soluções" para resgate de parâmetros.

**1. Suporte a subpastas e base da URL relativa**

A chave "REQUEST_URI" da variável global `$_SERVER`, retorna a query inteira de uma URL. Isso pode ser um problema caso o script seja executado dentro de um subfolder. Também pode ser um problema caso o nome do arquivo seja explicitamente invocado na URL.

Exemplo: `http://localhost/pasta/parametro1/parametro2`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` retornará `/pasta/parametro1/parametro2`.

Se não identificarmos a base da URL relativa, teremos um conflito nos parâmetros.

O script abaixo faz essa verificação e também checa a existência do nome do arquivo do script, para os casos de *URL amigável falsa*.

Exemplo: `http://localhost/pasta/index.php/parametro1/parametro2`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` retornará `/pasta/index.php/parametro1/parametro2`.

**2. Suporte a URL normal, URL amigável, URL amigável falsa e Linha de comando (cli).**

No protocolo HTTP, o formato padrão e normal de parâmetros numa URL é o tradicional formato usando o argumentador de parâmetros.

O argumentador de parâmetros é representado pelo símbolo de interrogação (?).

Exemplo: `http://localhost/?p=foo/bar`

Chamamos isso de "URL normal".

Na URL amigável, também conhecida como "reescrita de URL", "URL rewrite" ou "URL açucarada", omite-se os parâmetros e o argumentador.

Exemplo: `http://localhost/foo/bar`

Para que isso funcione, o web server do ambiente deve possuir suporte a reescrita de URL. O web server mais popular é o Apache. Nesse exemplo, abordaremos somente sobre o seu uso com o Apache.

A URL amigável falsa é uma espécie de gambiarra que permite criar URLs amigáveis sem uso de recursos de reescrita de URL como o mod_rewrite do Apache.

Essa técnica surgiu devido a demanda do mercado em usar URL amigável em servidores de hospedagem sem suporte a reescrita de URL.

Exemplo: `http://localhost/index.php/foo/bar`

A linha de comando, também conhecida como CLI ou CLI SAPI, no PHP, é um meio de execução ignorado ou pouco suportado pela maioria das aplicações. Normalmente os frameworks mais populares do mercado oferecem todos os recursos aqui descritos, incluindo execuções em linha de comando.

Exemplo: `/caminho/do/compildor/php -f /caminho/do/script/index.php foo/bar`

No script abaixo, há suporte a interface de linha de comando (shell prompt).

Para a linha de comando, os parâmetros seguem o mesmo formato de uma URL amigável pois o resultado final de quaisquer um dos meios de execução será o mesmo.

**3. Suporte a URL amigável pelo método POST**

É recomendável não misturar métodos de requisição diferentes numa única requisição.

Exemplo:

```
<form action="pagina.php?foo=bar" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="test" value="ok" />
</form>
```

O parâmetro "action" da tag `form` possui parâmetros no formato `GET`. Porém, o método definido é "POST". Para resgatar esses dados em pagina.php, será necessário invocar `$_GET` para obter o valor de "foo" e `$_POST` para obter o valor de "test"

Tecnicamente não há problemas sérios como conflito de dados ou coisa do gênero. O problema nisso é organização e também dificuldade em implementar um meio de resgatar tais dados de forma flexível e dinâmica.

A fim de descomplicar, recomenda-se que adote um padrão de envio de dados por um único método.

No caso de envio de dados pelo método POST, uma URL amigável deixa de ter sentido pois os parâmetros não são visíveis na URL como no método GET.

Por isso também, recomenda-se não utilizar URL amigável para envio de dados pelo método POST.

Contudo, devemos nos adequar as demandas do mercado. Tal como o uso de URL amigável falsa, o script abaixo também provê um meio de permitir URL amigável pelo método POST. Nesse caso, o endereço da URL amigável é ignorado e somente os parâmetros enviados pelo método POST são extraídos.

**Magic Quotes!**

É um recurso nativo do PHP que, quando ativado, adiciona caracteres de escape nos valores dos parâmetros recebidos.

Esse recurso foi descontinuado no PHP 5.3.0 e removido completamente na versão 5.4.0. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Atualmente muitos servidores de hospedagem possui um ambiente com PHP 5.3 ou mesmo versões inferiores como 5.1 ou 4 com *Magic Quotes* ativado.

O script abaixo possui essa verificação como um recurso de retrocompatibilidade, permitindo ser executado em versões antigas do PHP.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('html_errors',FALSE);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);

define('CHARSET', 'UTF-8');

ini_set('default_charset', CHARSET);

if (PHP_VERSION < 5.6)
{
    ini_set('mbstring.http_output', CHARSET);
    ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding', CHARSET);
}


/**
Caminho base da URL relativa.
Exemplo, caso execute esse script sob um subolder: http://localhost/pasta/index.php
O valor de $path_base deve ser "/pasta/" ($path_base = '/pasta/';)
Caso execute na raíz do endereço, apenas defina com uma barra "/" ($path_base = '/';)
*/
$path_base = '/';

/**
Nome deste arquivo que executa os scripts.
*/
$index_file_name = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

/**
Verifica se está sendo executado por interface de linha de comando.
Caso a constante PHP_SAPI retorne a string "cli", retorna "true". Caso contrário, "false".
*/
$cli_mode = (strtolower(PHP_SAPI) == 'cli'? true : false);

/**
Caso $cli_mode for falso, resgatamos os parâmetros da chave "REQUEST_URI".
Caso $cli_mode for true, os parâmetros serão resgatados da chave "argv".
*/
$uri = (!$cli_mode? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : (isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])? $_SERVER['argv'][1] : ''));

/**
Remove o caminho base do parâmetro resgatado de $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ou $_SERVER['argv'].
*/
if (!empty($uri))
{
    $len = mb_strlen($path_base.$index_file_name);

    if ($path_base.$index_file_name == substr($uri, 0, $len))
        $uri = substr($uri, $len);

    $len = mb_strlen($path_base);

    if ($path_base == substr($uri, 0, $len))
        $uri = substr($uri, $len);
}

/**
Caso não esteja sob interface de linha de comando (cli), executa os processos dentro da condicional.
*/
if (!$cli_mode)
{
    /**
    Resgata o método da requisição caso não esteja sob interface de linha de comando (cli).
    */
    $method = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])? strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) : null);

    /**
    true: Permite URL amigável pelo método POST.
    false: Nega URL amigável pelo método POST.

    Recomendável manter como false.
    */
    $allow_mode_rewrite_by_post = false;

    /**
    Verifica se os parâmetros possuem formato normal ou formato de URL reescrita.
    */
    if (substr($uri, 0, 1) == '?')
        $mode_rewrite = false;
    else{
        if ($method == 'POST')
        {
            $mode_rewrite = ($allow_mode_rewrite_by_post? true : false);
        }else{
            $mode_rewrite = true;
        }
    }

    /**
    A query parece provir de uma URL normal.
    */
    if (!$mode_rewrite)
    {

        /**
        Nome do parâmetro padrão para recebimento de nomes de rotas.
        Exemplo: http://localhost/?p=foo/bar
        */
        $route_parameter = 'p';

        /**
        Nessa condição, resgatamos um parâmetro padrão que contém a rota.
        O nome do parâmetro é definido na variável $route_parameter.
        */
        $uri = (isset($GLOBALS['_'.$method][$route_parameter]) ? $GLOBALS['_'.$method][$route_parameter] : null);

        /**
        Suporte para servidores com magic_quotes ativado.
        */
        if (!empty($uri) && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            $uri = stripslashes($uri);
    }
}


/**
Exemplos de uso

URL normal: http://localhost/index.php?p=foo/bar ou http://localhost/?p=foo/bar
URL amigável falsa: http://localhost/index.php/foo/bar
URL amigável: http://localhost/foo/bar
Linha de comando: /caminho/do/compildor/php -f /caminho/do/script/index.php foo/bar

Para URL amigável sob o módulo Rewrite Module do Apache, o arquivo .htaccess deve conter o seguinte código:

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+) /


*/

/**
Configura o ccharset no cabeçalho.
*/
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.CHARSET);

/**
Imprime "URI: foo/bar"
O output será sempre a parte relevante da URI. 
Exemplo: localhost/foo/bar, localhost/?p=foo/bar e os outros meios, retornam "foo/bar"
*/
echo 'URI: '.$uri;
```

**SEO, HTML link rel="alternate"**

Para efeitos de SEO, é importante preocupar-se com as informações referente a URL. Caso o sistema permita acesso aos diversos formatos de URL, recomenda-se definir `link rel="alternate"` apontando para a URL "oficial".

Isso evita que mecanismos de busca, como o google bot, penalizem a página como duplicata de alguma outra página previamente indexada.

Num exemplo prático, temos a seguinte URL `http://localhost/foo/bar` que pode também ser acessada como `http://localhost/?p=foo/bar`.

Caso o bot de busca tenha acesso a URL normal, o sistema deve identificar que a requisição não proveio da URL padrão e adicionar ao cabeçalho HTML a tag `<link>` cujo atributo *rel* seja definido como "alternate". Para o atributo `href`, defina a URL padrão (oficial) onde o bot deve ir de fato e ignorar penalizações. Exemplo:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost/foo/bar" hreflang="en" />
```

Comment: Seria possivel aplicar essa solução no wordpress? estou utilizando variáveis na URL desse jeito `localhost/wp/?layout=2` como fazer desse? `localhost/wp/layout/2`

Answer (score 11):

<sub>**.HTACCESS**</sub>

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

<sub>**ROTA**</sub>

```
// www.site.com/carros/novos -> carros/novos
$url = ltrim( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , PHP_URL_PATH ) , '/' );

$rotas = explode( '/' , $url );
$rotas[0] // carros
$rotas[1] // novos
```

Próximo passo é pegar as informações da URL, depende do seu sistema.
Você pode usar explode ou PREG com suas rotas definidas.

> É um exemplo bem superficial sobre roteamento de URL

Answer (score 5):

Nesse exemplo que vou citar estou utilizando apenas um parâmetro.

URL normal:

```
http://www.site.com.br/pagina.php?conteudo=criativo
```

URL amigável:

```
http://www.site.com.br/pagina?conteudo=criativo
```

Primeiro, separe o conteúdo antes e depois do sinal de igual:

```
$separaigual  = explode("=", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Agora que passamos a URL para um `array` temos as duas *strings* abaixo:

```
$separaigual['0'];  // ficou:  /pagina?conteudo
$separaigual['1'];  // ficou:  criativo
```

Veja que nesse exemplo conseguimos pegar perfeitamente o parâmetro `criativo` da variável `conteudo`.
Mas, e para pegar a variável `conteudo`?

Para pegar o nome da variável `conteudo`, devemos separar o antes e o depois do sinal de interrogação:

`$separainterrogacao = explode("?", $ separaigual['0'])`;

Agora temos um `array` com as duas *strings*:

```
$separainterrogacao ['0'];  // ficou:  /pagina
$separainterrogacao ['1'];  // ficou: conteudo
```

Temos então agora a o `$separainterrogacao ['1']` sendo a variável `conteudo` e o  `$separaigual['1']` sendo o parâmetro `criativo`.

Para um exemplo de seleção de um *post* em um banco de dados via SQL teríamos:

```
"SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nomedopost = '$separaigual[1]'"
```

E uma verificação com um condicional `if` por exemplo poderíamos fazer assim:

```
If($separainterrogacao ['1'] === "criativo"):
   echo "mostre o conteúdo";
else:
   echo "Não mostre o conteudo";
endif;
```

Pode não ser a melhor maneira, mas é uma maneira pratica que encontrei.

Answer (score 2):

As respostas acima são excelentes soluções, mas vou lhe fazer um pergunta muito simples, porque não usa um **framework?** Todos já resolvem seu problema por padrão.
Além de crescimento e amadurecimento profissional, com frameworks modernos você estará aprendendo boas práticas e novas normas do php, lhe recomendo os seguintes:

**Iniciante:**

- Codeigniter

**Intermediário:**

- Laravel
- CakePHP
- Yii

**Avançado:**

- Symfony
- Zend

Se você deseja ser um profissional, recomendo altamente o uso de um framework, para aprendizado, posteriormente você pode até criar o seu próprio.

Comment: Não se esqueça do Drupal!

Comment: Postei em particular os que eu conheço e já tive contato, mas, até onde me lembro, o Drupal é CMS não?!

Comment: É verdade, me confundi

Comment: Oi, eu sou o [Advogado do Diabo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advogado_do_Diabo) e meu cliente não quer usar um Framework porque: primeiro ele quer aprender como as coisas funcionam; sabendo isso é mais fácil operar e manipular um Framework; e depois disso tudo, muito mais fácil criar seu próprio Flamework ;) Mas obviamente, pode ser tudo feito ao contrário, como você propõe..!

Comment: Eu aconselho o estudo da linguagem, as novas práticas do php moderno e uma boa lida nos PSR http://www.php-fig.org/ e também uma lida nos conceitos OOP e MVC. Aprender diretamente um framework realmente limita o conhecimento geral/completa da linguagem, mas também é uma forma mais rápida de aprender todos conceitos em geral, fica a escolha da pessoa. Minha humilde opinião.

Answer (score 2):

> Não consegui fazer funcionar utilizando apenas as permissões de
>   reescrita. Para funcionar mesmo tive também que adicionar ao código
>   este trecho de **debug de caracteres** na página de listagem dos
>   links. Utilizei para um sistema de notícias onde eu tinha destaques
>   que levava para a página aberta, vejam:

### Debug

```
<?php
//URL DEBUG CHARACTERS
function encodeSEOString($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("`\[.*\]`U", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace('`&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;`i', '-', $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $string = preg_replace("`&([a-z])(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig|quot|rsquo);`i", "\\1", $string);
    $string = preg_replace(array("`[^a-z0-9]`i", "`[-]+`"), "-", $string);
    return strtolower(trim($string, '-'));
}
```

?>

### Link

```
<a href='/noticia/".encodeSEOString{$read['titulo']}.".'>ABRIR NOTICIA</a>
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^noticia\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ noticia.php?titulo=$1
```

### Download

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7k9YhCyYGeST216aGNBVVoydEU/view?usp=sharing