# Como pegar variável com $_GET

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Olá, no meu htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=download&k=$1 [QSA,L]
```

E no download.php

```
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];
echo $k;
```

Porem retorna esse erro quando eu acesso `download/?k=aaaa` ou `download/?aaaa`

```
Notice: Undefined index: k
```

index.php

```
<body>
    <?php
        require 'config/tratarUrl.php';
        include $pag;
    ?>
</body>
```

tratarUrl.php

```
<?php
$pUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT)));
$sUrl = (empty($pUrl) ? "index" : $pUrl);
$url = array_filter(explode('/', $sUrl));

if (count($url) > 1) 
{
$cont = 1;
foreach ($url as $arg) 
{
    define("PARAM" . $cont, $arg);
    $cont++;
}
} 
else if (count($url) == 1) 
{
if (file_exists(DIR_PAGES . $url[0] . '.php')) 
{
    $pag = DIR_PAGES . $url[0] . '.php';
} 
else 
{
    if($url[0] != 'index')
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES . '404.php';
    }
    else
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES . 'home.php';
    }
}
} else {
$pag = DIR_PAGES . '404.php';
}
```

Comment: O que retorna com `var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);`?

Comment: Retorna `string(13) "url=download/`, estranho ele não estar pegando o `aaaa` no final.

Comment: Creio que sua regra deva ser `RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=download&k=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Continua retornando o mesmo erro `Undefined index: k` e mesma mensagem `string(13) "url=download/"`

Comment: Já modifiquei a pergunta.

Comment: Altere essa linha `# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1` com o `#` no inicio; essa regra está pegando tudo `(.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua regra deve conter `[QSA,L]`.

> A flag `QSA` significa que vai aceitar uma seqüência para consulta.
>
> A flag `L` significa que se a regra corresponder, não irá processar a cadeia seguinte

---

Mude a ordem da sua regra:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?a=download&k=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

---

Comment: Agora quando eu digito `site.com/download/?aaaa` retorna `Objeto não encontrado!`

Comment: Editei a perguntar para você entender melhor.

Comment: Mas sua regra para *download* é `site.com/download/arquivo`, e não `site.com/download/?aaaa`. Seguindo a lógica da regra, o parâmetro `a` é *download*, e o parâmetro `k` corresponde ao arquivo.

Comment: Quando eu entro em `site.com/download/aaaa` ele literalmente acessa o arquivo `/aaaa`, porem eu gostaria de quando acessar `site.com/download/aaaa` eu apenas pegasse a informação "aaaa" mas continuasse entrando no arquivo `download`.

Comment: Aparentemente por causa do seu loop. Veja se essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27535/13412), ou a do Daniel ajudam no seu código.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema, porem surgiu outra duvida, para esse tópico não ficar sobrecarregado vou criar um novo.